# Real-time drawing synchronization between PKCanvasView on iPad and external screen

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, pencilkit, pkcanvasview

**Situation:**
I'm developing an iPad app using `SwiftUI`, and I have an external screen connected to the iPad. In my app, I want to provide a drawing feature using `PKCanvasView`. The goal is to allow users to draw on the iPad screen and have the drawing display in real-time on the external screen. How can I achieve this synchronization between the `PKCanvasView` on the iPad and the external screen?

I have tried using an `ObservableObject` and then accessing the canvas property to pass it to the ExternalCanvas View

When I try this, I can draw on the iPad but when I connect an external monitor it removes the `PKCanvasView` off the iPad screen and puts it on the external monitor.

**EDIT:** I have also been back and forward with ChatGPT for almost 3 hours trying to get a resolution, but it was unable to suggest anything, mainly because it didn't seem to grasp the concept of what I was trying to achieve and they more it tried the further it got from the desired outcome

```
class SharedData : ObservableObject {
   @Published var canvas : PKCanvasView = PKCanvasView()
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import PencilKit
struct ExternalView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var shared : SharedData
    var body: some View {
            ExternalCanvas(canvasView: shared.canvas)
    }
}
```

```
struct ExternalCanvas: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var canvasView: PKCanvasView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 15)
        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PKCanvasView` is a subclass of `UIView`. A `UIView` can only have a single superview. So you cannot use the same instance of `PKCanvasView` in two places (built-in screen and external screen) at the same time. You need one `PKCanvasView` for each place where you want to show the drawing, and you need to keep the `drawing` property of all the `PKCanvasView`s in sync.

`PKCanvasView` only updates its `drawing` when a stroke ends, so you cannot quite get all the views to synchronize in "real-time". This is what you get:

[image: Screen recording of the iOS simulator showing an iPhone 13 mini and an external display. Both screens show a PKCanvasView. I draw a few squiggles on the iPhone screen and the squiggles appear on the external display.]

First, I wrote a wrapper for `PKCanvasView`:

```
struct PKCanvasViewWrapper: View {
    @Binding var drawing: PKDrawing

    var body: some View {
        Rep(spec: self)
    }
}
```

I like to keep my `UIViewControllerRepresentable` types private, so that wrapper is just a `View`, and it uses a private type named `Rep`:

```
extension PKCanvasViewWrapper {
    typealias Spec = Self

    fileprivate struct Rep: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        var spec: Spec

        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> Controller {
            return Controller(spec: spec)
        }

        func updateUIViewController(_ controller: Controller, context: Context) {
            controller.update(to: spec)
        }
    }
}
```

The `Controller` type is a `UIViewController` that manages the `PKCanvasView`:

```
extension PKCanvasViewWrapper {
    fileprivate class Controller: UIViewController {
        private var spec: Spec
        private let canvas: PKCanvasView

        init(spec: Spec) {
            self.spec = spec

            canvas = PKCanvasView()
            canvas.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
            canvas.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen)

            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

            self.view = canvas
            canvas.delegate = self
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }

        func update(to spec: Spec) {
            self.spec = spec

            if canvas.drawing != spec.drawing {
                canvas.drawing = spec.drawing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Controller` type conforms to `PKCanvasViewDelegate` so that the canvas can notify it when the drawing changes:

```
extension PKCanvasViewWrapper.Controller: PKCanvasViewDelegate {
    func canvasViewDrawingDidChange(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
        if canvasView.drawing != spec.drawing {
            spec.drawing = canvasView.drawing
        }
    }
}
```

In a real app, you might want to add more properties to the `PKCanvasViewWrapper` type to specify how to configure the `PKCanvasView`. Then, in the `Controller`'s `update(to:)` method, you'd need to use those properties to configure the `PKCanvasView`.

Anyway, I then wrote an `ObservableObject` type to hold the shared `PKDrawing`:

```
class AppModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var drawing: PKDrawing

    init() {
        drawing = PKDrawing()
    }
}
```

I added an `appModel` property to my `AppDelegate` to make it available to all scenes:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let model = AppModel()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a SwiftUI view to appear on the internal screen:

```
struct InternalRootView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: AppModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Internal Screen")
            PKCanvasViewWrapper(drawing: $model.drawing)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                .border(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

and I wrote a scene delegate to create that view and show it in a window:

```
class InternalSceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
            let scene = scene as? UIWindowScene
        else { return }

        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: InternalRootView(model: appDelegate.model))
        window.isHidden = false
        self.window = window
    }
}
```

I copied the view and scene delegate for the external screen, just changing "Internal" to "External" everywhere.

Finally, I updated the "Application Scene Manifest" in the Info tab of my app target:

```
Application Scene Manifest
  Enable Multiple Windows NO
  Scene Configuration (2 items)
    Application Session Role (1 item)
      Item 0 (Default Configuration)
        Delegate Class Name: $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).InternalSceneDelegate
        Configuration Name: Default Configuration
    External Display Session Role Non-Interactive (1 item)
      Item 0 (Default Configuration)
        Delegate Class Name: $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExternalSceneDelegate
        Configuration Name: Default Configuration
```

You can find the full project [in this github repo](https://github.com/mayoff/pkexternal).